# AWS Node.js JSON put error

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I have the following code I am trying to upload to DynamoDB local host using Node.js.

Is there a possible work around. For the following error?

```
Unable to add event undefined . Error JSON: {
  "message": "One of the required keys was not given a value",
  "code": "ValidationException",
  "time": "2016-06-28T04:02:26.250Z",
  "requestId": "970984e4-3546-41f0-95f9-6f1b7167c510",
  "statusCode": 400,
  "retryable": false,
  "retryDelay": 0
}
```

Here is the code. I would like the `Item: {}` to accept whatever values may be present, and add them to the table.

```
var AWS = require("aws-sdk");
var fs = require('fs');

AWS.config.update({
    region: "us-west-2",
    endpoint: "http://localhost:8000"
});

var docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();

console.log("Importing movies into DynamoDB. Please wait.");

var allMovies = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('moviedata.json', 'utf8'));
allMovies.forEach(function(movie) {
    var params = {
        TableName: "Movies",
        Item: {
            "year":  movie.year,
            "title": movie.title,
            "info":  movie.info,
            "twitter": movie.twitter
        }
    };

    docClient.put(params, function(err, data) {
       if (err) {
           console.error("Unable to add movie", movie.title, ". Error JSON:", JSON.stringify(err, null, 2));
       } else {
           console.log("PutItem succeeded:", movie.title);
       }
    });
});
```

Comment: what is your partition and range key? If you have defined one of the attributes (year, title, info or twitter) as keys, it must have some values. Otherwise, you wouldn't be able to insert the data into table. The workaround is to define your own key and populate it on your code rather than relying on input data. However, I am not sure whether this approach would satisfy the query pattern. I can update the detailed answer if you can provide your key attributes. The answer is very much dependent on that and your query pattern.

Comment: Thank you @notionquest this helped me. I was use to uploading docs to Parse without worrying about partition and range key. I will reformat my JSON dataset.

Answer (score 0):

As you are looping over a promise call, you need a safeguard that the current promise resolves before you begin the next.

```
var AWS = require("aws-sdk");
var fs = require('fs');
const tableName = 'Movies';
AWS.config.update({
  region: "local",
  endpoint: "http://localhost:8000"
});

var docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();

console.log("Importing movies into DynamoDB. Please wait.");

var allMovies = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('moviedata.json', 'utf8'));

for (let i = 0, p = Promise.resolve(); i < allMovies.length; i++) {
    p = p.then(_ => new Promise(resolve =>
        setTimeout(function () {
          var params = {
              TableName: tableName,
              Item: {
                  "year":  allMovies[i].year,
                  "title": allMovies[i].title,
                  "info":  allMovies[i].info
              }
          };
          docClient.put(params, function(err, data) {
             if (err) {
                 console.error("Unable to add movie", allMovies[i].title, ". Error JSON:", JSON.stringify(err, null, 2));
             } else {
                 console.log("PutItem succeeded:", allMovies[i].title);
             }
          });
          resolve();
        }, 10)
    ));
}
```